# C Free Dynamic Array of Structs - Why are they not contigous

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, free

I'm struggling with a C struct which must hold a dynamic array of smaller structs:

```
typedef struct issueStruct {
    int data;
} issue;

typedef struct volumeStruct {
    issue* collection;
    size_t elements;
} volume;
```

I can dynamically create as many issue structs as I like within a volume struct's array.  I can also iterate through that array:

```
int main(){
    volume* TimeMagazine = (volume*)malloc(sizeof(volume));
    TimeMagazine->collection = (issue*)malloc(4 * sizeof(issue));
    TimeMagazine->elements = 4;

    issue* ptr = TimeMagazine->collection;
    int i;

    // Populate & iterate through array:
    i = 0;
    while(i < TimeMagazine->elements){
            ptr->data = 100*i;
            printf("%d)  %d\n", i, ptr->data);
            i++;
            ptr = ptr+i;       // Advance ptr
    }
    return 0;
}

OUTPUT:
[Linux]$ gcc -Wall magazines.c
[Linux]$ ./a.out
0)  0
1)  100
2)  200
3)  300
[Linux]$
```

So far, so good.  When I step through the above in GDB, everything looks okay, although I notice that the issue structs do not seem to have contiguous memory addresses.  Here's the memory addresses I saw:

```
issue 0)  0x602030
issue 1)  0x602034
issue 2)  0x60203c
issue 3)  0x602048
```

That gave me some pause; I would have assumed all issues would be 4 bytes apart, as `sizeof(issue) = 4`.  More seriously, when I modify my "iterate through" code to free up the elements of the array, my code seg faults.  Specifically, it faults when it tries to free the second issue.  Here's the code:

```
    i = 0;
    ptr = TimeMagazine->collection;
    issue* ptr2 = ptr;
    while(i< TimeMagazine->elements){
            printf("freeing %d...\n", i);
            i++;
            free(ptr2);           // free ptr2
            ptr2 = ptr = ptr+i;   // advance ptr & ptr2
    }
```

Here's the error (GCC on Linux):

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000137c034 ***
```

So I'm sure I'm missing something here, but not sure what.  Can someone recommend an effective way to free() the array elements?

Many thanks!

-Pete

PS - There are a lot of "freeing structs in array" posts, but none seemed to precisely match what I am doing.  So I am posting this in the hope that my version of this question is unique.

Comment: One `malloc`, one `free`. That's the rule. At the moment you have one `malloc` for the entire `collection` array and then you try to have multiple `free` calls with one for each element in the array (though your pointer arithmetic is wrong as pointed out in the answer below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while(i < TimeMagazine->elements){
        ptr->data = 100*i;
        printf("%d)  %d\n", i, ptr->data);
        i++;
        ptr = ptr+i;       // Advance ptr
}
```

You are using wrong pointer arithmetic in `ptr = ptr+i`, should be `ptr = ptr+1` or you access outside of the bounds. Same for the `free` section.

And as pointed out by @kaylum in comments: you are calling `free` in a loop, this is also wrong, you can `free(TimeMagazine->collection);` at once since you are reserving space for `4` elements in the same block.

Comment: The same thing on the memory free part.

Comment: Also, use format `"%p"` to print pointers. There's no guarantee that `"%d"` will do what you want.

Comment: @Gene, it seems that OP is printing the address in gdb (not in the program), `ptr->data` is an `int`

Comment: Another problem seems to be one `malloc` but multiple `free`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is a side note regarding contiguous memory and structs containing dynamic arrays. For the actual answer  refer to [the answer given by @KeineLust](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40602354/4025095).

As mentioned before, one `malloc` == one `free`.

However, unmentioned is the fact that contiguous memory often performs better due to caching considerations.

This means that your `struct volumeStruct` would perform better if both it's memory and the dynamic array were allocated using the same `malloc` call.

There are two common ways to accomplish this.

One, using the same structures you currently have (I fixed your loop to have `ptr = ptr + 1`, so we don't go out of bounds):

```
int main(){
    volume* TimeMagazine = (volume*)malloc(sizeof(volume) + (4 * sizeof(issue)) );
    TimeMagazine->collection = TimeMagazine + 1; // pointer arithmetics
    TimeMagazine->elements = 4;

    issue* ptr = TimeMagazine->collection;
    int i;

    // Populate & iterate through array:
    i = 0;
    while(i < TimeMagazine->elements){
            ptr->data = 100*i;
            printf("%d)  %d\n", i, ptr->data);
            i++;
            ptr = ptr+1;       // Advance ptr
    }

    free(TimeMagazine);

    return 0;
}
```

Another option (I think this was introduced in C99), is to add a variable length array at the end of the struct. This saves you the 8 (or 4) bytes required for the `collection` pointer.

i.e.:

```
typedef struct issueStruct {
    int data;
} issue;

typedef struct volumeStruct {
    size_t elements;
    issue collection[];
} volume;

int main(){
    volume* TimeMagazine = (volume*)malloc(sizeof(volume) + (4 * sizeof(issue)) );
    TimeMagazine->elements = 4;
    // no need to assign a value for TimeMagazine->collection

    issue* ptr = TimeMagazine->collection;
    int i;

    // Populate & iterate through array:
    i = 0;
    while(i < TimeMagazine->elements){
            ptr->data = 100*i;
            printf("%d)  %d\n", i, ptr->data);
            i++;
            ptr = ptr+1;       // Advance ptr
    }

    free(TimeMagazine);

    return 0;
}
```

The big upside is CPU memory caching and simpler code. The fact that we're saving two system calls per object (one `malloc` and one `free`) is irrelevant in most cases.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant.  One thing that confuses me...  You don't actually have any malloc() calls for the issue structs.  I understand that the malloc()s for the issues is folded into the malloc() call for the "TimeMagazine" volume struct.  That carves out memory for the issues.  Then the issue* ptr points to the collection of TimeMagazine.  So when you increment ptr by +1, the compiler knows that "+1" really means "+sizeof(issue)" ?

Comment: @Pete , yes, the compiler knows that `sizeof(*ptr) == sizeof(issue)` and performs correct pointer arithmetics when you use `ptr += 1`. Pointers are no more than numbers representing (often virtual) memory addresses. There's no in-memory type data, so types are always controlled by the compiler which adjusts the pointer arithmetics accordingly.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  I've read about this aspect of C in plenty of documentation, but its a weird thing to get used to.  Thanks again!